# hiera() function and YAML hash lookups

Tags: puppet, hiera

How do I rewrite this YAML so it is more structured, then reference it in Puppet using hiera function?

---

Currently, I am working with a hieradata syntax that looks very flat and hard to read.

```
service::proxy::behind_reverse_proxy: true
service::proxy::proxy_timeout: 300
service::proxy::serverlist:
  - host1.fqdn
  - host2.fqdn
```

And grabbed these in a `params.pp` file, for example

```
$behind_reverse_proxy = hiera('service::proxy::behind_reverse_proxy', 'False')
$serverlist = hiera('service::proxy::serverlist')
```

---

I thought I could rewrite the YAML like so in an effort to make it more readable...

```
service::proxy:
  behind_reverse_proxy: true
  proxy_timeout: 300
  serverlist:
    - host1.fqdn
    - host2.fqdn
```

And updated the `params.pp` file according to

- [Hiera Key.subkey syntax](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/hiera_subkey.html#keysubkey-syntax)
- [interacting with structured data](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.3/puppet.html#interacting-with-structured-data-from-hiera)

```
$behind_reverse_proxy = hiera('service::proxy.behind_reverse_proxy', 'False')
$serverlist = hiera('service::proxy.serverlist')
```

However upon `puppet agent -t` that resulted in

> Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item service::proxy.serverlist in any Hiera data file and no default supplied

---

I think these are relevant

```
[user@server ~]$ facter -y | grep 'version'
facterversion: 2.4.4
puppetversion: 3.8.2
```

Comment: The Hiera key/subkey syntax is pretty new.  I'd have to do a bit of poking around to determine for sure exactly when it was introduced, but at least the documentation page you reference does not have a corresponding page for any Puppet version prior to 4.9.

Comment: Puppet 3 can be paired with any of several different versions of Hiera.  Which version do you have?

Comment: I'm very new to Puppet. Where would I check that? On the puppet agent, or server? And which command?

Comment: If you are using Hiera for your parameter lookups, then layering that through a `params.pp` is an extra point of failure with no added value. Also, is there anything preventing you from using a supported version of Puppet?

Comment: Hiera has a CLI.  You should be able to determine what version you have via the command `hiera --version`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have inherited this project from other developers, and it's not the best. Hence my efforts to rewrite this one module to get started

Comment: @JohnBollinger On the agent, I get `require': cannot load such file -- hiera`, and I don't think I have SSH access to the Puppet server

Comment: Well, it's in the environment in which the catalog builder runs that the Hiera version matters.  In a master/ agent arrangement, that would ordinarily be on the server, but if you're running into the error with the module's test suite then it's wherever you are running the test suite.  Do you confirm that the unmodified version of the module works without such errors in the environment in which you are testing?

Comment: Also, did the correction suggested by Jordan Running in his answer make any difference?

Comment: Haven't got a chance yet to run the suggested answer. The initial version shown in the question works without error, yes

Comment: @JohnBollinger Same error with the answer provided below

Comment: I think your issue is with the Hiera version.  v1 is [Puppet, Inc's recommended version for Puppet 3.8](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/#versions).  You need at least v2.0 for the key / subkey support, and I'm not sure whether v2.0  works with Puppet 3.  It's certainly not what comes in the tin.  Moreover, be aware that you must avoid applying such transformations to any data used in [automated data binding](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup).

Comment: Honestly, unless you are prepared to update your whole Puppet stack at least to version 4 (v5.0 was just released), I think you're asking for more trouble than you want.  And though the upgrade from 4 to 5 is supposed to be fairly painless, the one from 3 to 4 can be painful.

Comment: Hmm, well upgrading the infrastructure is out of my control. It's surprising to me that JSON and YAML are supported as hieradata but there's  no detailed support for arrays or hashes, only scalars.

Comment: @cricket_007, Puppet supports JSON and YAML arrays and hashes in hiera data, arbitrarily nested to any depth, as *values*.  Every version allows you to retrieve such values by their (scalar) keys, and to access their contents once retrieved.  What is not well supported until Puppet 4 is retrieving only *part* of a compound value via Hiera's lookup functions, which is what you're trying to do.  You can still restructure your data (that are not used in automated data binding); you just need to change your approach to accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment about how you can access your restructured data:

> ```
> service::proxy:
>   behind_reverse_proxy: true
>   proxy_timeout: 300
>   serverlist:
>     - host1.fqdn
>     - host2.fqdn
> ```

In your manifest, instead of this ...

> ```
> $behind_reverse_proxy = hiera('service::proxy.behind_reverse_proxy', 'False')
> $serverlist = hiera('service::proxy.serverlist')
> ```

... you might do this:

```
$proxy_info = merge(
    { 'behind_reverse_proxy' => false, 'serverlist' => [] },
    hiera('service::proxy', {})
)
$behind_reverse_proxy = $proxy_info{'behind_reverse_proxy'}
$serverlist = $proxy_info{'serverlist'}
```

The `merge()` function is not built-in, but rather comes from Puppet's (formerly PuppetLabs's) widely-used [stdlib module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib).  There's a good chance that you are already using that module elsewhere, but even if not, it may be well worth your while to introduce it to your stack.

Comment: I believe we do have using stdlib included. In the Puppetfile, there is `mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib', '4.6.0'`

Comment: Note that a stdlib-less solution for the hash merge in Puppet >= 4 is to use the `+` hash operator: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/lang_expressions.html#merging.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Hiera, but I think the problem is that you have a sequence (array) when you wanted a mapping (hash).

In the below YAML, the value of the `service::proxy` key is a sequence with three elements, each of which is a mapping with one key:

```
service::proxy:
  - behind_reverse_proxy: true
  - proxy_timeout: 300
  - serverlist:
    - host1.fqdn
    - host2.fqdn
```

What you probably wanted, though, was for `service::proxy` to be a mapping with three keys:

```
service::proxy:
  behind_reverse_proxy: true
  proxy_timeout: 300
  serverlist:
  - host1.fqdn
  - host2.fqdn
```

The examples in the Hiera docs you linked to seem to support this.

Comment: Good catch. Let me see what happens when I remove the sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error (updated question with the corrected YAML)